# IContextMenu Handler - Should ShellExecute or CreateProcess be used to InvokeCommand?

Tags: winapi, com, windows-shell

I've added a handler for the context menu in explorer to show items conditionally.   My question is now when it comes time to `InvokeCommand` should I use `ShellExecute` to run the .exe that needs to run, or should I use the `CreateProcess()`method?

Basically the way Windows would do it with static entries is what I'd like to duplicate.

TIA!!

Comment: This is about Shell, so ShellExecute is usually preferred but it ultimately depends on your context

Comment: It is your handler, use whatever makes sense for your use case.  But in general, if you are invoking an `.exe` directly then you should use `CreateProcess()`.

Comment: It's better to use `CreateProcess` from my viewpoint. [*An application can also invoke this method indirectly by calling ShellExecute or ShellExecuteEx and specifying a verb that is supported by the namespace extension or handler.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-icontextmenu-invokecommand#remarks) It looks a logical loop.